# Removing a KeyValuePair of an IReadOnlyDictionary in runtime?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

Is there a way to remove a KeyValuePair of an IReadOnlyDictionary at runtime using reflection? I do have key value.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but the method would depend on the concrete implementation. For example, for a [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlydictionary.cs,81a03f90c06edeb7), you could use reflection to grab the private `m_dictionary` member, then modify that to your heart's content.

Comment: By definition, an `IReadOnlyDictionary` is read-only... you can't modify it. Even if the actual implementation of the interface happens to be a writable dictionary, you're not supposed to know about it; if it's exposed as an `IReadOnlyDictionary`, it's a clear statement that you're not meant to modify it. What is the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Both comments solved my problem. In fact, I cannot modify an IReadOnlyDictionary, except when I'm working with their implementation using reflection. For my case, I made my own concrete class who implements IReadOnlyDictionary and this class had a IDictionary, something similar to ReadOnlyDictionary. Removing a kvp from this dictionary solved my problem. I appreciate both comments, thank you.